# C# wpf Ellipse width and height for two points

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, ellipse

I'm trying to draw a circle centered at point2 with radius "r". r's length should be long enough to be the distance between point1 and point2. I drew a picture to illustrate this. How can I calculate the correct width and height of the ellipse to draw it like this diagram? I know r can be calculated by taking the difference of the two points. However, afaik wpf only allows you to modify the width and height of the ellipse, not the radius.

Comment: It isn't letting me post a picture.

Comment: Wouldn't width and height just be r*2?

Comment: but isnt the width and height a little longer than the actual radius of the circle because of the corners of the box created around the circle? so you have to compensate for that?

Comment: If you mean you need to account for the Border element, then fine, but the difference is going to be awfully small. The border is usually 1 or 2 pixels wide.

Comment: You were right, it was simply 2 times the radius.

Comment: The width and height of the ellipse is just simply the diameter of the circle ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to drawing an Ellipse control is a Path with an EllipseGeometry:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="100,100" RadiusX="100" RadiusY="100"/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: This was a much easier and time efficient approach instead of programmatically trying to do it.

Comment: Please note also that this draws the center of the stroke on the outline of the geometry, whereas the Width and Height of an Ellipse control measure the outer bounds of the stroked shape.